# erro ao editar dados de uma página PHP para tabela Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Porque quando tento editar em uma tabela no Mysql e a quantidade de lenghts é alta, o programa não deixa editar? Ex: Dei um var_dump na query de edição...São so campos: id, titulo, txt1, txt2, txt3 porém, apresenta desta forma...

C:\wamp64\www\NI_x\adm\app\sts\processa\proc_edit_home_fr.php:33:string 'UPDATE sts_home_fr SET
                titulo='Dados do titulo',
                txt1='Et si vous… pouviez y voir plus ? Voir l’ invisible? Si vous étiez capable d’avoir accès à des informations cachées ? Si vous pouviez apprendre plus avec cette information supplémentaire? C’est ce que fait Xpectraltek. Nous fournissons des solutions d'imagerie qui permettent de voir au-delà de l'œil humain et d'en tirer des conclusions.  ',
                txt2='empr',              '... (length=631)

Não apresenta os dados inputados para o campo txt3...

porém, se eu fizer edição com poucos dados para cada campo, ele edita tranquilamente.

Na tabela está: 
id: (int) chave primaria
titulo (varchar) 100
txt1 (text)
txt2(text)
txt3 (text)

Quando eu libero o var_dump, ele dá continuidade no processamento, mas não atualiza nem tabela nem a visualização resultante da edição...podem me ajudar?

Comment: Montar o SQL como texto antes de executar está causando um erro de sintaxe, pois os seus valores têm aspas simples não escapadas. Se você simplesmente escapar as aspas, o código vai executar, mas será vulnerável a injeção de SQL. Use um dos métodos indicados no link do box amarelo do topo.

Comment: Olá Favaretto. Obrigado pela ajuda, mas o que VC quis dizer com escapadas?